# Multiple Data Sources In Single Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I am making two separate requests to obtain JSON from external sources, I have so far implemented the display of the data from the first request into my table view. My problem is, I need to combine both sets of data into a single table view and sort the data by a common key, which in this case is created_time. I understand I can use some form of array, but how would I go about doing this?

The first:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                     JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) {
                                         self.results = [json valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
                                         [self.tableView reloadData];
                                     } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                     }];

[operation start];
```

The second:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"];
             NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"count" : RESULTS_PERPAGE,
                                          @"q" : encodedQuery};

             SLRequest *slRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                     requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                               URL:url
                                                        parameters:parameters];

             NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
             slRequest.account = [accounts lastObject];             
             NSURLRequest *request = [slRequest preparedURLRequest];
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine the data from your external sources, you'll want to do the following for each response you get back.

Also, for the sake of the example, I'm assuming the objects you'll be dealing with are all dictionaries. If they aren't, you'll want to add some logic in the comparison block to get at the `created_time` value depending upon the type of object each one is.

```
NSArray *data = [json valueForKeyPath: @"data"];        // This is the data from your first example. You'll have to do the same for your second example.

NSMutableArray *allResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.results];
[allResults addObjectsFromArray: data];
[allResults sortUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    NSDictionary *dict1 = obj1;
    NSDictionary *dict2 = obj2;

    return [[dict1 objectForKey: @"created_time"] compare: [dict2 objectForKey: @"created_time"]];
}];

[self setResults: allResults];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Note you can just do `[allResults sortUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *dict1, NSDictionary *dict2) {`.  Also, you should definitely implement the check Jason recommends (that it is, in fact, an NSDictionary).  Otherwise, if your API sends the wrong response, it can make your app crash.